# Using Semaphors to create a thread safe stack in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, stack, mutex, semaphore

I'm trying to make a stack that I implemented thread safe using semaphors. It works when I push a single object onto the stack, but terminal freezes up as soon as I try to push a second item onto the stack or pop an item off of the stack. This is what I have so far and am not sure where I'm messing up. Everything complies right, but the terminal just freezes as previously stated

Heres where I create the stack

```
sem_t selements, sspace;
pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

BlockingStack *new_BlockingStack(int max_size)
{
    sem_init(&selements, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&sspace, 0, max_size);

    BlockingStack *newBlockingStack = malloc(sizeof(BlockingStack));
    newBlockingStack->maxSize = max_size;
    newBlockingStack->stackTop = -1;
    newBlockingStack->element = malloc(max_size * sizeof(void *));

    if (newBlockingStack == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (newBlockingStack->element == NULL)
    {
        free(newBlockingStack);
        return NULL;
    }

    return newBlockingStack;
}
```

And here are the Push and Pop:

```
bool BlockingStack_push(BlockingStack *this, void *element)
{
    sem_wait(&sspace);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);


    if (this->stackTop == this->maxSize - 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (element == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    this->element[++this->stackTop] = element;
    return true;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    sem_post(&selements);

}

void *BlockingStack_pop(BlockingStack *this)
{
    sem_wait(&selements);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);

    if (this->stackTop == -1)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        return this->element[this->stackTop--];
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    sem_post(&sspace);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For thread safety you already have mutex used (`pthread_mutex_lock(&m) and pthread_mutex_unlock(&m)`). Using such mutual exclusion is enough for that purpose. Once one thread obtains the mutex, other thread blocks on `pthread_mutex_lock(&m)` call.
And only the thread currently obtaining the mutex can call `pthread_mutex_unlock(&m)`.

Comment: i intended to only use mutex, but was told that for this assignment, I had to use semaphors

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTED CHANGES:

```
sem_t sem;
...
BlockingStack *new_BlockingStack(int max_size)
{
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 1);
    ...

bool BlockingStack_push(BlockingStack *this, void *element)
{
    sem_wait(&sem);
    ...
    sem_post(&sem);
    ...
```

Specifically:

- I would only initialize one semaphore object unless I was *SURE* I needed others
- I would use the *same* semaphore for push() and pop()
- `pshared: 0` should be sufficent for synchronizing different pthreads inside your single process.
- Initialize the semaphore to `1`, because the first thing you'll do for either "push" or "pop" is `sem_wait()`.

Answer (score -1):

OK, i was working on this and finally cracked the answer after doing a little bit of internet research and debugging my code. The error was the the mutex_unlock and the sem_post had to come before the return.

Take my pop for example:

```
void *BlockingStack_pop(BlockingStack *this)
{
    sem_wait(&selements);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);

    if (this->stackTop == -1)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        return this->element[this->stackTop--];
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    sem_post(&sspace);
}
```

notice how the **pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);**  and the   **sem_post(&sspace);** come after the return, they actually must be placed before every return like so:

```
void *BlockingStack_pop(BlockingStack *this)
{
...
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    sem_post(&sspace);
        return NULL;
...
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    sem_post(&sspace);
        return this->element[this->stackTop--];
...

}
```

Comment: Q: So why not get rid of the duplicate redundant "pthread_mutex"?  Just use one or the other locking?  Get rid of that unnecessary "sspace" vs. "selements", too: you just need ONE semaphore.

Comment: @FoggyDay I was using sspace to wait until there was at least one space in the stack before pushing to the stack, and then selements to then signal that theres at least one element after the push had occured. I used mutex to lock and unlock after the use of semaphors

Comment: IMO... That's silly :(  You only need *one* lock: either the stack is being updated (you're actively doing  a "push" or a "pop") ... or it isn't.